# Mootools Issue in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, mootools, joomla1.7

I am having an issue with Mootools. If you go to this page [RTDS](http://www.hanseninfotech.com/rtds) you'll notice a login button in the top right. On all other browsers (IE9, Safari, Chrome, and Firefox) the login works fine but it doesn't work in IE8. IE says its an error related to moo tools but I don't really know what it means or how to fix it. The error is as follows:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2;     .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C;  InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 8 Feb 2012 02:26:00 UTC


Message: 'null' is null or not an object
Line: 66
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://www.hanseninfotech.com/rtds/templates/beez5/javascript/md_stylechanger.js


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 473
Char: 25
Code: 0
URI: http://www.hanseninfotech.com/rtds/media/system/js/mootools-core.js
```

Has anyone ever seen this or have any information on how to fix this?

Comment: Post the code. The errors are useless without the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use Firebug for Firefox, you'll see there is an error on md_stylechanger.js script.

As it seems you don't use it (it modifies size of fonts), get rid of the file.

And update to joomla 2.5, 1.7 won't be supported any more soon.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the file and stopped getting the error but that still didn't solve it. What I did to fix it was remove the <a></a> and I used onClick="location.href.... instead and now it is working across all browsers. Thank you for your contribution.